# How to show an object inside of another object as a normal text or a string?

Tags: javascript

```
A = {
region1: {
city1: [option1, option2, option3],
city2: [option1, option2, option3]
},
region2: {
city1: [option1, option2, option3],
city2: [option1, option2, option3]
}
```

How can I make `city1` in `region2` show up in console.log as a normal text or string ?

For example if I right `A["region2"]["city1"][1]` in console.log the result will be `option2` and it will show up as normal text.
But if I write `A["region2"]["city1"]` the result will show all of the array inside of `city1`

I need `city1` to show up in console.log plain without the array inside of it nor anything else (just like a normal text or string)

I mean the object `city1` not the content of it just the object it self.

I need the result in console.log to be just like that (city1)

**(not the content of `city1`)**

Answer (score 0):

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is there to rescue

```js
console.log(A["region2"]["city1"].join(" "))
```

You can specify comma, space or anything you wish to split the elements inside `join`.

**UPDATE**

As the requirement is to display the key in console, you can traverse the keys of objects using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and so I use it to find the index of the key with value "city1" and then use that index to print it. This way, you can specify any desired key name.

```js
console.log(Object.keys(A["region2"])[Object.keys(A["region2"]).indexOf("city1")])
```

Comment: I'm not looking for anything in the array, I want to show the object `city1` it self as a string without showing the content of it.

Comment: @msa, Got it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an object-oriented approach involving the override of the `toString()` method

```js
function Area(name, regionList) {
    this.name = name;
    this.regionList = regionList;
}

function Region(name, cityList) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cityList = cityList;
}

function City(name, optionList) {
    this.name = name;
    this.optionList = optionList;
}

Area.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.name;
};

Region.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.name;
};

City.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.name;
};

var city = new City('Lugano', ['lago', 'montagna']);

var region = new Region('Ticino', [city]);

var area = new Area('Svizzera', [region]);

console.log(area.toString());
console.log(area.regionList[0].toString());
console.log(area.regionList[0].cityList[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object keys using the `Object.keys()`. Passing the A.region1 inside the function will return you the array `['city1', 'city2']` and then you can get the key that you want by its index.

```js
const obj = {
  'region1': {
    'city1': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'],
    'city2': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
  },
  'region2': {
    'city1': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'],
    'city2': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj.region1)[0]);
```